WP Toolkit failed create backup (Task is not responding)
I am going to repair some issues in a WordPress website and work on it in a staging site created by cPanel WP Toolkit. And now, I want to back up the staging site using the cPanel WP Toolkit too.
However, once I started, the process was stuck at 0% for hours, and I couldn't cancel the process.
The next day, it told me that the backup had failed: "Failed to back up site
Task is not responding".
What should I do now for expecting backup and restore with no issue in cPanel WP Toolkit?
